# How do I make a commutative diagram with LaTeX?

Tags: tikz-pgf, math-mode, diagrams, tikz-cd, xymatrix

How do I make a diagram like this? Thanks in advance[image]

Comment: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
 & \mathbb{F} \arrow[dl,"\mu"'] \arrow[dr,"\nu"] &  \\
 \mathbb{P} & & \mathbb{M}\\
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}`

Comment: Have you tried some code?

Comment: `\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone} 
\usepackage{amsfonts} 
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path 
(0,0) node (F) {$\mathbb{F}$}
+(-45:1.5) node (M) {$\mathbb{M}$}
+(-135:1.5) node (P) {$\mathbb{P}$};
\draw[->] (F)--(M) node[pos=.3,right]{$\nu$};
\draw[->] (F)--(P) node[pos=.3,left]{$\mu$};
\end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}`

Comment: @BlackMild Hey, thanks for the reply. Is there a way to make the arrows bigger? They are too short on my document. Also, How do I put it in the center of the page? Than

Comment: @marmot Thanks for the reply. The letters above the arrows do not appear for some reason

Comment: @ThalesCastro Most likely you are loading some babel package. Add `\usetikzlibrary{babel}` to the preamble of your document after `\usepackage{tikz-cd}`.

Comment: @marmot Works perfectly. Thank you very much.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved in the comments

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Such diagrams can be drawn with `tikz-cd`. This site is full of examples, and the manual is very well written.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
 & \mathbb{F} \arrow[dl,"\mu"'] \arrow[dr,"\nu"] &  \\
 \mathbb{P} & & \mathbb{M}\\
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

For bigger arrows, you can use `[line width=1pt]` or `[thick]` right after `\begin{tikzpicture}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{amsfonts} 
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick]
\path 
(0,0)       node (F) {$\mathbb{F}$}
+(-45:1.5)  node (M) {$\mathbb{M}$}
+(-135:1.5) node (P) {$\mathbb{P}$};
\draw[->] (F)--(M) node[pos=.3,right]{$\nu$};
\draw[->] (F)--(P) node[pos=.3,left]{$\mu$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}    
\end{document}
```

Comment: @marmot nope! my mind is free. My code is elegant, so I make it community wiki

Comment: @marmot I recommend you unretiring!

Comment: Your solution is original, but a `tikz-cd` one is more flexible and simpler.

Comment: @CarLaTeX: with (original) plain tikz, I can fine-tune every commuative diagram. I don't know why `tikz-cd` is more flexible! I think `tikz-cd` is well-fitted for one who are not familiar with tikz. The amount of time for learning new syntax, new commands of `tikz-cd` is equal the amount of time for learning basic TikZ.

Comment: It's more flexible because you don't have to set the positions explicitly. It's more convenient if you have to add new elements.

Answer (score 2):

Here there is my proposal using the same tips of `tikz-cd` but with another package called `xy`. I have added `\usepackage[bb = boondox]{mathalfa}` to give you the same mathematical double struck capital. With the option `@R=.6pc@C=.6pc` you can increase or decrease the lenghts of the rows R, or the columns C.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}
\usepackage[bb = boondox]{mathalfa}
\begin{document}
\xymatrix@R=.6pc@C=.6pc
   { & \mathbb{F} \ar[dl]_{\scriptscriptstyle\mu} \ar[dr]^{\scriptscriptstyle\nu}  & \\
     \mathbb{P} & & \mathbb{M}
   }
\end{document}
```

### ADDENDUM:

For further information on how put the labels neighbours to the arrows, there is specific my question with an answer in this link:
[Labels closer to the arrows with xy package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/502320/labels-closer-to-the-arrows-with-xy-package)