# Labels closer to the arrows with xy package

Tags: arrows, labels, xy-pic, xymatrix

Few hours ago I have added my answer for this question
 [How to make a math diagram on LaTex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/502187/how-to-make-a-math-diagram-on-latex/502219#502219)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}
\usepackage[bb = boondox]{mathalfa}
\begin{document}
\xymatrix@R=.6pc@C=.6pc
   { & \mathbb{F} \ar[dl]_{\scriptscriptstyle\mu} \ar[dr]^{\scriptscriptstyle\nu}  & \\
     \mathbb{P} & & \mathbb{M}
   }
\end{document}
```

but the labels are a little too far from the arrows. I have not found in the manual what I am looking for. Is there a way to bring the labels closer to the arrows?

[image]

Comment: `\xymatrix@R=.6pc@C=.6pc
   { & \mathbb{F} \ar[dl]_{\scriptscriptstyle\mu\!\!} \ar[dr]^{\!\!\scriptscriptstyle\nu}  & \\
     \mathbb{P} & & \mathbb{M}
   }`

Comment: @marmot Kind marmot therefore there is not into the documentation to bring the labels closer to the arrows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible solution. You have to set the values by hand.

[image]

The idea is to print the default arrow with no labels and then insert an invisible arrow translated by some amount in parallel, with the label on it.

Observe the `\ar[dl] \ar@<3pt>@{}[dl]_{}`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}
\usepackage[bb = boondox]{mathalfa}
\begin{document}
$\xymatrix@R=.6pc@C=.6pc{
& \mathbb{F}    \ar[dl] \ar@<3pt>@{}[dl]_{\scriptscriptstyle\mu} 
                \ar[dr] \ar@<-3pt>@{}[dr]^{\scriptscriptstyle\nu}
& \\
\mathbb{P} & & \mathbb{M}
}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: I saw this in the manual, but I didn't think it was related to a shorter distance of the labels.

Comment: @Sebastiano, well, to be true, it moves everything: the arrow and label. It is very useful to draw 2 parallel arrows.

Comment: With lot of sincerity he'd move the labels from one side to the other: pag. 6 of xyguide.pdf :-). I approved however your code! My best regards.

Comment: @Sebastiano, sorry, I didn't follow your comment about pg 6. I see no problems there.

Answer (score 3):

Use `\labelmargin`, see 24i on page 40 of the reference manual.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}
\usepackage[bb = boondox]{mathalfa}

\begin{document}

\xymatrix@R=.6pc@C=.6pc{
 & \mathbb{F} \ar[dl]_{\scriptscriptstyle\mu}
              \ar[dr]^{\scriptscriptstyle\nu}  & \\
   \mathbb{P} & & \mathbb{M}
}

\labelmargin-{2pt}

\xymatrix@R=.6pc@C=.6pc{
 & \mathbb{F} \ar[dl]_{\scriptscriptstyle\mu}
              \ar[dr]^{\scriptscriptstyle\nu}  & \\
   \mathbb{P} & & \mathbb{M}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: "Gentilissimo" egreg thank you very much for your answer. At this moment I can not upvoted you. I have finished all my votes :-(. Thank you very very very much. But for respect of Sigur the check mark remains to him. I hope that my English is correct.

Comment: @Sebastiano That's your choice, between a proper solution and a hack.

Comment: @Sebastiano, don't worry and feel free to change your decision.

Comment: @Sigur I never liked to disrespect other people. Fairness and humility come first. I am the first to make mistakes and when I make mistakes I do apologize. In my questions almost everyone has a green check. If they are not there it is because I have evaluated them at the same level. You were both very good. Always every best to you and the good users.

Comment: @egreg Done! +1 for your very good answer.